# HQL. How to create a query that returns all the Lines with a List<Point> between dates

Tags: hibernate, jpa, select, hql, jpql

I have two entities: Line and Point

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "line")
public class Line {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "line_id")
    private List<Point> points;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "point")
public class Point {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "x")
    private LocalDateTime x;

    @Column(name = "y")
    private int y;
}

select * from line;
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 | 
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | lineA                |         
|  2 | lineB                |  
+----+----------------------+  

select * from point;
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| id |              x             |     y   |  line_id |
+----+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     1   |      1   |
|  2 | 2017-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     2   |      1   |
|  3 | 2018-01-11 02:00:00.000000 |     1   |      1   |
|  4 | 2019-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     3   |      1   |
|  5 | 2015-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     2   |      2   |
|  6 | 2016-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     1   |      2   |
|  7 | 2017-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     3   |      2   |
|  8 | 2018-01-01 02:00:00.000000 |     2   |      2   |
+----+----------------------------+---------+----------+
```

What the HQL query should look like so that it returns a list of all lines (List) containing points between two dates?

```
entityManager.createQuery("select distinct l from Line l join l.points p where p.x between :sd and :ed)").setParameter("sd", LocalDateTime.of(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)).setParameter("ed", LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)).getResultList()
```

Such a request will return the lines in which at least one point is in the interval between dates. In this case, the line will contain all the points that it has. But I need to return all the lines containing only points between these two dates.

I suspect it's pretty simple. But due to the fact that I am new to hql and in sql, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried something like `p.x < :ed AND p.x > :sd` ?

Comment: It seems to be the same as in my example. The problem is that the lines should not contain points that are not included in these dates, but as a result of this query I will get lines that will contain all the points if there is at least one point in the line included in this interval. But if the line does not have such a point, then I will not get such a line. I need to always get all the lines, but that the points of each of them are between dates. And even if the line has no such points, I want to get this line, but with an empty list of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently resolved by splitting into separate requests. first, all lines gets, and only then, for each, the points gets